# MSYS2 MinGW64 gdb vs WSL gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw-w64, msys2

So I wanted to try to use gdb from terminal for educational purposes. I have gdb from MSYS2 MinGW64 and also WSL on my system. For simple example I used the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main // or main.exe if on Windows
```

I used the following sequence of commands:

```
> gdb
(gdb) file main // or main.exe if on Windows
(gdb) layout next
(gdb) run
```

So as expected program enters infinite loop. If I press Ctrl+C, I expect gdb to stop program and show line in source, where it've stopped. I get the expected behavior when using gdb in WSL. But when I try to use MinGW64 gdb in windows, there are number of things which go wrong:

1. I can only use gdb from windows terminal app. If I use powershell or cmd it just closes when I enter run in gdb.
2. I have to use `set new-console on` in gdb for it to work.
3. When I press Ctrl+C, I get the following:
   [image: c]
   So how do I make MSYS2 MinGW64 gdb work like expected?

Comment: @dewaffled Thank you for the reply. It almost does. I tried it and it have worked, but then I added print statement inside `while` loop and when I enter `info threads` I don't see thread that executes `main()` anymore.

Comment: @AisecNory And what do you see instead?

Comment: @ssbssa Sorry, for late reply. Basically if I add `std::cout << counter << std::endl;` inside while loop, after call to `info threads` all listed threads execute code inside ntdll.dll. Maybe It's due to simplicity of the code in example, and because flushing stream with `std::endl` takes much more time than incrementing counter. Either way I closed question as duplicate.